# summarise and then summarise_at in one dplyr chain?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame of clustered data which I'm aggregating by cluster to provide summary data on.

I would like to create a new column based on cluster count n() and then do mean and sum over a list of vars:

```
# works fine
nums <- c("mpg", "disp", "cyl")
mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise(cnt = n())
```

Looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
   carb   cnt
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     7
2     2    10
3     3     3
4     4    10
5     6     1
6     8     1

# does not work, returns error message:

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: object
> 'disp' not found. In addition: Warning message: In mean.default(mpg) :
> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

nums <- c("mpg", "disp", "cyl")
mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise(cnt = n()) %>% summarise_at(.vars = nums,
                                                                    funs(mean, sum))
```

Goal is to have the tbl above but with new column cnt being the count of observations in each group.

Comment: Where is `nums` column after the `summarise`?

Comment: Do you need `mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% mutate(cnt = n()) %>% group_by(cnt, add = TRUE) %>% summarise_at(.vars = nums,
                                                                     funs(mean, sum))`

Comment: @akrun nums is ```nums <- c("mpg", "disp", "cyl")```. Your code block looks right except is it not grouping by newly created var cnt (```group_by(cnt, add = TRUE)```)? I want to keep the grouping variable on carb only and then return the count of obs in each carb, along with sum and mean of the vars in nums

Comment: In that case `mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise(cnt = n()) %>% cbind(., summarise_at(mtcars, .vars = nums, funs(mean, sum)))`

Comment: Thank you @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `mutate` to create the 'cn't by 'carb', then add 'cnt' also as the grouping variable before doing the `summarise_at`

```
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(carb) %>% 
   mutate(cnt = n()) %>%
   group_by(cnt, add = TRUE) %>% 
   summarise_at(.vars = nums, funs(mean, sum))
```

Comment: Actually, now that I'm looking at the data, all the summary data are the same for each observation. ```mtnums <- c("mpg", "disp", "cyl")
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(carb) %>% 
  summarise(cnt = n()) %>% 
  cbind(mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise_at(mtcars, .vars = mtnums, funs(mean, sum)))```
I tried editing the last line to ```cbind(mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise_at(mtcars, .vars = mtnums, funs(mean, sum)))```  which gave error "Error: Can't create call to non-callable object"

Comment: @DougFir  Based on your comment, I think you need the updated solution

Comment: Interesting. Are we grouping on carb or cnt here though? The goal is to group on carb feature only but it's hard to tell from reading this. What is add = T doing?

Comment: @DougFir  It is grouping both by 'carb' and 'cnt', but the 'cnt' doesn't really matter as we already have values that are replicated by creating the column with `mutate`.  `add=TRUE` implies to add the 'cnt' also as grouping variable.

Comment: Ah it has clicked now. Thanks again